# how to make an http link to launch an app in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have tried with URL scheme and I was successful in launching the app from safari by typing the `"app_name://"`and also using `"www.appname://"`. But what I exactly wanted to achive is, when I click on the website link for e.g.: `"www.appname.com"` it has to lauch the app if the app is in staled in the device

Answer (score 1):

One of the features Apple introduced with iOS9 is the support of **Universal Links**. With that feature clicking on www.appname.com in Mobile Safari or a `UIWebView` / `WKWebView` will lead the user into your app (if the app is installed and you enabled this feature in your app). This also works for links in other apps that use `openURL:` (like in Mails)

For users with an iOS < 9 the link will be opened in Mobile Safari.

Here are the steps that you have to do to enable this feature.

**1. Configure your app to register approved domains**

- Registered your app at developers.apple.com
- Enable ‘Associated Domains’ on your app identifier
- Enable ‘Associated Domain’ on in your Xcode project
- Add the proper domain entitlement
- Make sure the entitlements file is included at build

**2. Configure your website to host the ‘apple-app-site-association’ file**

- Acquire SSL certification for your domain
- Create structured ‘apple-app-site-association’ JSON file
- Sign the JSON file with the SSL certification
- Configure the file server

For more details on how to implement those steps check out this [tutorial](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) or [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12) on this feature:

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9

Comment: @joem Thanks for the link and also for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
    BOOL installedFacebook = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]];
    if (installedFacebook) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com"]];
    }
```

Comment: can u please explain where i need to put this code.....because if u are pasting this code in appdeligate, then its obvious that u have in instaled the app

Comment: The button, addTarget

Comment: In the method which is triggered by the button.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer, but how do I know the exact 'app_name'? For instance, facebook's 'app_name' is "fb" rather than "facebook".

Comment: its not on button click ..... application needs to launch when somebody Click on a particular URL in browser, let me give you an eg: for an instance if you hit www.facebook.com on your browser , If Facebook app is installed in your Device then it should automatically launch the Facebook App